# Left Alt doesn't compose

Tags: raspbian

When I want to invoke a shortcut that contains Alt, only left Alt works. Holding right Alt doesn't make any difference. Examples are Ctrl+Alt+F1 to switch to virtual terminal 1, or Alt+s to invoke search in the Midnight Commander.

I can reproduce this using the `us` and `hu` xkb layouts and didn't try others. I use Raspbian 9.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please don't call it "compose", this is a special function for combining base characters and diacritics. You hit one after another the *Compose* key (or key combination, keysym is *Multi_key*), then all the diacritics, then the base character. E.g. Compose, _, ", a → ǟ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's intentional.

- The left alt key is usually mapped to *modifier 1*.
- The right alt key in contrast is usually mapped to *modifier 5*.

You need this *modifier 5* to access the fifth and sixth (+shift) level of characters mapped onto the other keys. E.g. mod5+e gives you the € sign.

You can create a custom keymap or (simpler) play with the **xmodmap** utility to remap single keys.

`xmodmap -e "remove mod5 = ISO_Level3_Shift"`

`xmodmap -e "add mod1 = ISO_Level3_Shift"`

Comment: *"this is intentional"* -> I don't think this is the case with a US keyboard configuration; both my Alts perform the same way (even though on this laptop the right one is marked 'Alt Gr', i.e., presumably could be assigned a different code).

Comment: The number of weird European keyboard layouts is endless, even if the OP wrote he tried the `us` layout, I think there were still remains of the hungarian mapping in use. This whole X11 keymap business is very crude.